# TYPO3: Simple way to add a button to a page, other than html?

Tags: typo3

What's the simple way, i.e., wysiwyg, to add a button to a page in typo3, other than html?

Comment: 2 down-votes on the first question, outch ;-) Hope my answer is helping though!

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Do you mean in the frontend or backend, etc.? I assume you mean frontend, but what should the button do? Do you want to attach JavaScript to it etc. Based on the context, different solutions might apply.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are two WYSIWYG editors in TYPO3 I give you now links to add new classes to e.g. `<a>` tags:

With RTE (TYPO3 < 8):
http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2015/10/02/typo3-6-2-rte-link-stil-class-hinzufuegen-1643/ (description unfortunately in German, but Google Translate can help)

With CKEditor (TYPO3 >= 8):
https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the extension `gridelements` including FlexForm for configuration. Then it can be used as common content-element.

Another (first) approach I dismissed was configuring CKEditor. As I needed a container for even several buttons perhaps I never knew how to solve it in time, so I switched to the solution with `gridelements`.
Here it is:

**Flexform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <color.select>
                <TCEforms>
                    <label>Button-Color (leave empty for individual color)</label>
                    <config>
                        <type>select</type>
                        <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                        <items>
                            <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                            <numIndex index="1">
                                <numIndex index="0">brown</numIndex>
                                <numIndex index="1">#740e01</numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                            <numIndex index="2">
                                <numIndex index="0">sand</numIndex>
                                <numIndex index="1">#ad9a63</numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                            <numIndex index="3">
                                <numIndex index="0">orange</numIndex>
                                <numIndex index="1">#f0811b</numIndex>
                            </numIndex>
                        </items>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </color.select>
            <color.input type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Button-Color individual</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>input</type>
                        <renderType>colorpicker</renderType>
                        <size>10</size>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </color.input>
            <link type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Button-Link</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>group</type>
                        <internal_type>db</internal_type>
                        <allowed>pages</allowed>
                        <size>1</size>
                        <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                        <minitems>0</minitems>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </link>
            <text type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Button-Text</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>input</type>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </text>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

In the gridelement-record in BE you can reference some xml-file in a filestorage like `fileadmin` but per PhpMyAdmin you also can enter something like `EXT:your_extension/Configuration/FlexForm/Button.xml`. You also could add the folder with the xml-files in an own filestorage with read-access only, then it could be chosen by the BE-dialogue.
Also you could enter the XML directly in the corresponding field in the gridelements-record without referencing the XML-file.

**TypoScript for button in `gridelements`:**

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    5 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    5 {
        prepend = COA
        prepend {
            wrap = <div class="btn-container btn-full-size">|</div>
            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                data = field:flexform_text
                stdWrap.typolink {
                    parameter.data = field:flexform_link
                }
                stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject = COA
                stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10.data = field:flexform_color.input
                    10.stdWrap.override.data = field:flexform_color.select
                    10.stdWrap.override.if {
                        isFalse.data = field:flexform_color.select
                        negate = 1
                    }
                    10.wrap = <p class="btn" style="background-color:|">
                    20 = TEXT
                    20.value = |</p>
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The number 5 in the top has to be replaced by the uid of the corresponding gridelement where the flexform is loaded. There will be added automatically some grid-configuration for rows and cols, just ignore it (rows:0, cols:0).

The HTML-wrapper in TypoScript you can vary of course and the CSS you have to add by yourself ;-)

So surely HTML is involved somehow but the editors can add buttons without using directly HTML but only a form.

Comment: Can you describe what your code does? I think it is a lot of code for a "simple button" and right now, I am not even sure what the OP wants in the first place.

Comment: Gridelements have the option to include FlexForms.
I used this option to offer a selector for different buttons, here only different in color.
Furthermore you've fields for button-text and button link.
As gridelements is always fighting with compatibility issues related to the TYPO3 core I wouldn't advise it on pages that shall have newer code. Nevertheless there are other options nowadays like the extensions `mask`, `container` or individual solutions to implement those options.
It offers a very clean and simple option for a distinct challenge I think the code amount is justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give the extension mask a chance: 
[https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/][1]

With this you are able to create your own content elements with input fields in the backend for all inputs that should be customised. It is one of my favourite extensions.